# Why process.communicate() return tuple of NoneType?

Tags: python, popen

Below program, launches subprocess and communicate via pipes,

```
import json
import math
import subprocess
import sys
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        websites = f.read().splitlines()
    numberOfProcesses = int(sys.argv[2])
    perProcess = math.ceil(len(websites) / numberOfProcesses)
    for i in range(numberOfProcesses):
        sites = websites[i*perProcess:(i+1)*perProcess]
        with open("/tmp/list-{}.txt".format(i), "w") as f:
            f.write("\n".join(sites))
    t0 = time.time()
    processes = []
    for i in range(numberOfProcesses):
        p = subprocess.Popen(
            ["python3.6", "naive-checker.py", "/tmp/list-{}.txt".format(i)]
        )
        processes.append(p)
    # Gather the results
    for process in processes:
        result = process.communicate()
        print('result:',result)
    t1=time.time()
    print("Total time getting website status took {0:1f} seconds", format(t1-t0))
```

---

`result` shows `(None, None)` instead of `(stdout, stderr)`, where each subprocess is,

```
import json
import requests
import sys
import time


def website_statuses(websites):
    statuses = {}
    for website in websites:
        response = requests.get(website)
        status = response.status_code
        if not statuses.get(status):
            statuses[status] = 0
        statuses[status] += 1
    return statuses


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        websites = f.read().splitlines()
    t0 = time.time()
    print('From this subprocess, status code: ', json.dumps(website_statuses(websites)))
    t1 = time.time()
    print("For this subprocess, getting website statuses took {0:.1f} seconds".format(t1-t0))
```

---

`list.txt` is file of websites.

Output:

```
$ python3.6 dummy.py list.txt 3
 From this subprocess, status code:  {"200": 11}
 For this subprocess, getting website statuses took 5.3 seconds
 From this subprocess, status code:  {"200": 9}
 For this subprocess, getting website statuses took 6.8 seconds
 From this subprocess, status code:  {"200": 11}
 For this subprocess, getting website statuses took 9.8 seconds
 result: (None, None)
 result: (None, None)
 result: (None, None)
 Total time getting website status took {0:1f} seconds 10.265882730484009
$
```

---

**Question:**

Why `result` shows tuple of `NoneType`?

Comment: But where is communication through the pipes?

Comment: We are not Google. We are not the documentation. [Read the docs.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Answer (score 3):

You should look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate):

> `communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdout_data, stderr_data)`. The data will be strings if streams were opened in text mode; otherwise, bytes.
>
> Note that if you want to send data to the process’s stdin, you need to create the `Popen` object with `stdin=PIPE`. Similarly, to get anything other than `None` in the result tuple, you need to give `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.

As you did not specify any output pipe while creating your [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) object, the returned values are two `None` while calling `communicate()`.

You may try to fix it with:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["python3.6", "naive-checker.py", "/tmp/list-{}.txt".format(i)],
     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [`Popen.communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) documentation:

> Similarly, to get anything other than `None` in the result tuple, you need to give `stdout=PIPE` and/or `stderr=PIPE` too.